# Drawing the same legend for the multiple spatial figures

Tags: r, plot, raster, r-sp, labeling

I have a for loop that makes interpolation and plots raster graphs by spplot.
It gives a single color bar but labels change in every plot.
You can see the difference below.
[image]
[image]

I want to use the same color bar with same labels in ssplot, but I could not plot the graphs according to the same map legend.

Here is final part of the code

> for (...) {
>
> > ...
>
> WElev.IDW = idw(formula = variable~1, locations = spdf2, newdata = r.pts)
>
> mypath <- file.path("C:","...", paste("WElevMonth", colnames(variable), ".png", sep = ""))
>
> png(filename = mypath)
>
> print(spplot(WElev.IDW["var1.pred"]))
>
> dev.off()   }

Answer (score 2):

## `stack()` your plots, and `spplot` the `RasterStack`

```
s <- stack(raster1, raster2)
spplot(s)
```

The resulting plot will have one common legend.

---

If you want all the plots independent of one another, but want to set the limits and breaks of the color scale, use the `at` argument. Pass `at` a vector of breaks. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728194/how-do-i-fix-a-color-scale-bar-in-several-spplots).

First, stack all of your rasters so you can quickly calculate the min and max of the stack. The use these values to inform your legend limits and breaks.

```
# max and min of the stack
max_r  <- cellStats(s, max) # max of raster stack: legend upper limit
min_r  <- cellStats(s, min) # min of raster Stack: legend lower limit
breaks <- (max_r - min_r)/15 # increase denominator for more breaks
lab    <- seq(min_r, max_r, by = breaks) # create the vector of legend breaks

# now run your for loop and within `spplot`, set the same legend with `at`
for(i in 1:n){
  spplot(raster, at = lab)
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rich Pauloo, `stack` works for me but my aim is to plot every graph separately.